# How to create a pdf when a client of Android application has requested the creation of a document

Tags: android, node.js, pdf, birt

I have developed the android app to generate a document.

I use nodejs, the server performs communication with the http Android App.

If the client of the Android app has requested the creation of the document, I want to create a document by using the birt.

The server would like to ask to create a pdf by sending to birt data created by the user.

In this case, I want to know how the server to ask to create a pdf birt.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just pass the report parameters to BIRT with an open as PDF in hyperlink via apache?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the report parameters

```
    response.setContentType( birtEngine.getMIMEType( format ));

if( format.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf") ){
            PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption( options );
            pdfOptions.setOutputFormat("pdf");
            pdfOptions.setEmbededFont(true);
            pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE);
            pdfOptions.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(pdfOptions);
}
```